# What is this chart called? How do I reproduce it in a web browser?

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, web

I'm perfectly aware this is a google away. Unfortunately I don't know the **name** of the chart I'm looking for.  So I'm unable to make a reasonable search for plugins or API's. Please be kind.

What is this type of charts called?

**What i want to do:**
Draw a chart similar to below in a webbrowser, given input as a list of "sizes". Preferably with a jquery plugin or javascript API.

In the image below the sizes happens to be Disk-sizes.

[image]

Comment: The screenshot makes this application come to my mind: http://w3.win.tue.nl/nl/onderzoek/onderzoek_informatica/visualization/sequoiaview/. They also call it "treemaps".

Answer (score 4, accepted):

This is called a Tree Map.  You can reproduce using a number of JavaScript libraries.  Here are a couple:

1. [Protovis](http://mbostock.github.com/protovis/ex/treemap.html)
2. [D3.js](http://mbostock.github.com/d3/ex/treemap.html)

Note:  D3 is actually a rewrite of Protovis.

Comment: Wow thats way more functionality than i expected! Thanks!

Answer (score 7):

It is a [Treemap](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Treemapping) chart. You can use Google's API to recreate it on the web:

http://code.google.com/apis/chart/interactive/docs/gallery/treemap.html

Answer (score 5):

It is called a **Treemap**.

See http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Treemapping.

Answer (score 3):

Well, the screenshot is straight from http://www.derlien.com, where they call it a ["treemap."](http://www.cs.umd.edu/hcil/treemap-history/index.shtml)